# Api fetching is showing "Network request failed" after mutiple api calls per minute

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, server

Im using react native for developing mobile applications. In that i mistakenly called an api call more than 50 times in a minute. After that now API fetch doesn't work properly either slow or doesn't work properly. What can i do now?

Comment: Attach your existing code into this

Comment: its not code based. Its like i called api fetch call too  many times in a minute. it stopped calling fetch call from my app.. so there isn't any code to show.its whole project

Comment: without code no one can understand jutst put portion of fetch code

Comment: Improve your question by adding your codebase into this. Otherwise, no one will able to answer the question. Before posting a question on StackOverflow make sure you follow the guidelines how to ask question

Comment: Im saying that my fetch call or anything doesn't have any problem. i called my api call more than the limit a server has. Now api calls which was working fine doesn't work now bcz server rejecting network request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark here, since there isn't much info given: your api server is throttling connections. For instance if you are using a free ngrok account you will be throttled after 30 calls in a minute.

You can fix by connecting to your localhost or by preventing your code from hitting the api so many times. E.g. have a mock response saved in your code so that you can iterate the frontend without hitting the API repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted.